# google maps not applying style

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps with kml and I want to display only country labels. by default it only show plain simple world map with nothing on it. https://gateway.spectrumasa.com/qc/mcmap/

my original code

```
var myOptions = {
        zoom : currentZoomLevel,
        center : latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        minZoom: 2, 
        maxZoom: 20,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    };  


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), myOptions);
```

new code with style

```
var styleArray = [
                      {
                        featureType: "all",
                        stylers: [
                          {  visibility: "off" }
                        ]
                      }/*,{
                        featureType: "road.arterial",
                        elementType: "geometry",
                        stylers: [
                          { hue: "#00ffee" },
                          { saturation: 50 }
                        ]
                      },{
                        featureType: "poi.business",
                        elementType: "labels",
                        stylers: [
                          { visibility: "off" }
                        ]
                      }*/
                    ];


    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.91654, 15.31326);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom : currentZoomLevel,
        center : latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        minZoom: 2, 
        maxZoom: 20,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        styles :styleArray /*[ { "featureType": "administrative.country", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] } ]*/
    };  


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), myOptions);
```

Comment: A satellite map doesn't have anything to style.

Comment: can i not add country labels to sattellite map

Comment: Sure.  But not with the Google Maps Javascript Styled Map functionality.  You have to add the labels yourself.  BTW, styling the labels on a HYBRID map doesn't seem to work at all (from a quick test).

Comment: how would i add the labels myself? as a kml file?

Comment: is it possible to style the terrain map to look like sattellite and then add country labels?

Comment: @geocodezip see my answer. Seems to work with the HYBRID map style.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but I may have done something wrong.

Comment: i have updated my site to use hybrid. country labels showing, thanks

Comment: Bizarre.  At zoom level 3, no country labels show on a HYBRID map, zoom level 4 they start showing up.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v72pudy7/2/)

Comment: yes, i just noticed the same

Answer (score 3):

For someone who is struggling with Google Maps not using defined styles, I'd like to point out that styling is **not working unless you have a valid API key**.

It was a bit confusing because Google Maps are working without the API key with dark overlay saying "For development purposes" so I didn't expect that some feature would be silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually can get what you want by using the `HYBRID` map style. Turn off everything, then turn on only the `administrative.country` labels.

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.368465, 4.903921),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    styles: [{
        'featureType': 'all',
            'elementType': 'all',
            'stylers': [{
            'visibility': 'off'
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }]
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/c90w3r6m/)</kbd>